# Как с помощью curl после авторизации перейти на нужную страницу?

Tags: php, curl, авторизация, csrf, pfsense

Необходимо авторизоваться на сервере pfSense и перейти на нужную страницу. С авторизацией вроде разобрался. А как дальше перейти не пойму.
Всегда, что бы ни делал, в $result выгружается главная страница. Пробовал использовать сохранённые в файле куки, результат тот же.

Не знаю, поможет ли чем-то для ответа, но в консоли подобное работает, а выглядит так.

```
curl -L -k --cookie-jar cookies.txt http://1.1.1.1:7979/ | grep "name='__csrf_magic'" | sed 's/.*value="\(.*\)".*/\1/' > csrf.txt;
curl -L -k --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt --data-urlencode "login=Login" --data-urlencode "usernamefld=username" --data-urlencode "passwordfld=password" --data-urlencode "__csrf_magic=$(cat csrf.txt)" http://1.1.1.1:7979/ > /dev/null; 
curl -L -k --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt http://1.1.1.1:7979/status_openvpn.php
```

```
<?php
    $url = "http://1.1.1.1:7979";
    $urlTo = "http://1.1.1.1:7979/status_openvpn.php";
    
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    
    $cookies_file = 'cookies.txt';
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies_file);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies_file);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    //print_r($html);
    
    //Получаем csrf
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    
    $nodes = $xpath->query("//input[@name='__csrf_magic']");
    $node = $nodes->item(0);
    
    //Сохраним в переменную
    $csrf = $node->getAttribute('value');
    //print_r($csrf);
    
    $post = [
        '__csrf_magic' => $csrf ,
        'login' => 'Login',
        'usernamefld' => $username,
        'passwordfld' => $password
    ];
    
    //Авторизация
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    
    
    //Переходим на нужный url, НО КАК??
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $urlTo);
    
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    
    if (curl_errno($curl)) print curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($curl);
    
    print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно разделить вызовы и не смешивать все в одну кучу. Смотрите пример [тут](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch11_04.htm):

```
$cookie_jar = tempnam('/tmp','cookie'); // log in
$c = curl_init('http://bank.example.com/login.php?user=donald&password=b1gmoney$');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar);
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

// retrieve account balance 
$c = curl_init('http://bank.example.com/balance.php?account=checking');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

Comment: Я так пробовал, но как быть с csrf ? Если я разделяю запрос, то в следующем меня выкидывает на страницу авторизации. Не понимаю, как в таком случае быть

Comment: Передавайте их с нужным запросом, если понадобится - то добавляйте в оба.

Comment: Я еще раз попробовал разделить вызовы, как вы советовали. Закрыл первый curl сеанс, где была авторизация (которая работает). Открыл новый сеанс, где мне надо с уже полученными cookies обратиться к странице $urlTo. Но оно возвращает мне страницу авторизации, как будто я не авторизировался в прошлом сеансе.